# why use tagCode to caculate the deliverTime in ScheduleMessageService of rocketMQ

Tags: rocketmq

the method executeOnTimeup of ScheduleMessageService caculate the deliverTimestamp ,if the cqUnit.isTagsCodeValid() return true the tagsCode is tag hasCode,why can use this to caculate the time

```
CqUnit cqUnit = bufferCQ.next();
   long offsetPy = cqUnit.getPos();
   int sizePy = cqUnit.getSize();
   long tagsCode = cqUnit.getTagsCode();
   if (!cqUnit.isTagsCodeValid()) {
         long msgStoreTime = ScheduleMessageService.this.brokerController.getMessageStore().getCommitLog().pickupStoreTimestamp(offsetPy, sizePy);
       tagsCode = computeDeliverTimestamp(delayLevel, msgStoreTime);
    }
   long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long deliverTimestamp = this.correctDeliverTimestamp(now, tagsCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not what `tagsCode` is meant to be. As `tagsCode` in CQUnit represents the address for CQ extend files, which should not be utilized as a timestamp here. It should be another variable replacing the `tagsCode` usage for the `deliverTimestamp` here.